# UPDATE Query vs Reference Table?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

The postgres database in question receives monthly updates, in the form of new tables. I am trying to work out which concept is most efficient to perform the task which I will describe below.

Table1 has a StoreNumber column; its contents refer to a geographical location. This number will always match the same location. To help our analysts use the data, I have been running a CASE function right after the new tables are added each month, which will add a new column defining the location name.

Now, to me this feels efficient, however I am being challenged and it is suggested that a reference table is a much better method of providing the location information.

It is hard to find information out there on using reference tables - Which is my struggle for finding an answer to this myself!

Comment: Postgres - will also add this to the first sentence!

Comment: Unless those who challenge you can explain _why_ their suggestion is "better", that is, what metric it improves and how much, I think you can safely ignore them.